# EHcache does not work in spring

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am now applying EHcache to my web application by means of SpringModules EHcache support.

However, it does not work. No exception thrown though.

ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache>
  <diskStore path="c:\\myapp\\cache"/>
  <defaultCache
      maxElementsInMemory="500"
      eternal="true"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
  <cache name="WorldExpoCache"
      maxElementsInMemory="500"
      eternal="true"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
</ehcache>
```

Excerpt of my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- EHCache configuration -->
    <ehcache:config configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>   

<ehcache:proxy id="WorExpoDAO" refId="worldExpoDAO"> 
       <ehcache:caching methodName="grabcategory" cacheName="WorldExpoCache"/>  
    </ehcache:proxy>

    <bean id="worldExpoDAO" class="com.cn.dao.WorldExpoDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="mySessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Certainly, I have a method called "grabcategory" sitting in my DAO class.
However, when this method fired up second time, related data was still retrieved from underlying database rather than from cache.

P.S.: I did include all required jars into my application

Why was that? Can anybody tell me where I did wrong?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Modules is no longer maintained, and does not work properly with the current versions of Spring and EhCache.

Unfortunately, the caching functionality provided by Spring Modules doesn't really have a replacement, you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the caching functionality of Spring Modules does have a replacement. EhCache Annotations for Spring has emerged, and is in fact a lot easier to use.

http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/

Answer (score 1):

The [@Cachable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable) annotation was introduced in the Spring 3.1 release. It can be [configured](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache) to use Ehcache as backend.